# Leer Excel versiones viejas

Tags: java, excel, web, genexus

Genexus GX17u2, generador Java, plataforma web.

Tengo un sistema externo que tiene una salida en excel que pretendo leer a través de un objeto:

```
ExcelDocument
```

El problema está en que la extensión del archivo es **xls**, y al intentar abrirlo **&ExcelDocument.Open(&RutaExcel)** **&ExcelDocument.ErrDescription** da el error:

```
Could not open file
```

Si abro el archivo desde excel 2007 o superior (lo abre en modo compatibilidad) y lo guardo  con extensión **xlsx** funciona perfecto.

La consulta es:

¿Será posible desde genexus abrir directamente el excel con extensión xls sin tener que hacer esa conversión? El tema es que son muchos exceles y el proceso de conversión implica una mala experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Qué son esos datos al comienzo de la pregunta?

Comment: Version de Genexus, generador y plataforma

Comment: Hola Bruno, podes probar generar una planilla nueva desde esa versión de GX con extensión xls. Hice pruebas y logré crearla y luego si corro de nuevo el código, la leo sin problemas. 
Cómo posible WA quizás puedas tener una mini rutina que si la extensión es "xls", usas el método "rename" del tipo File para cambiar a "xlsx". 
Eso podría servirte?

Comment: Hola Marce, gracias por comentar. Excel no permite abrir el archivo una vez renombrado desde xls a xlsx. Creo que GX debería poder abrir exceles de todas las versiones sin problemas, para evitar malas experiencias de usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno,

con el generador Java se pueden leer planillas tanto xls como xlsx. La versión de poi que usamos (4.1.2), soporta esto.

Según las pruebas realizadas el problema que estás teniendo es el reportado en el siguiente link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050957/notole2fileexception-while-reading-xls-file-in-apache-poi-4-0-1

Vale aclarar que tu puedes crear una planilla sin problemas. El problema se presenta con planillas de un 3ero.

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones!